# получить и вывести json данные

Tags: php, ajax, json

применил ваш скрипт из цикла уроков "каталог товаров" хлебные крошки, пытаюсь его сделать посредством ajax json, вот что получается

класс хлебных крошек

```
class Get_bredcrumps
{

    public   function breadcrumbs($array, $id)
    {
        if (!$id) return false;
        $count = count($array);
        $breadcrumbs_array = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ($array[$id]) {
                $breadcrumbs_array[$array[$id]['id']] = $array[$id]['title'];
                $id = $array[$id]['parent'];
            } else break;
        }
        return json_encode($breadcrumbs_array);
    }
}
```

класс возвращает результат: **{"968":"phones","970":"iphone"}**

аякс, как в него эти данные возвращать???

```
dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
                        var tr_str = "<div>";
                        var len = response.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            var id = response[i].id;
                            var title = response[i].title;


                            tr_str +=
                                "<a>" +title + "</a>";
                            tr_str += "</div>";
                        }
                        $(".breadcrumbs").html(tr_str);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let jsonObj = '{"968":"phones","970":"iphone"}',
  responseData = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
  
$.each(responseData, function (idx, el) {
  console.log(idx + ' ' + el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
success: function (response) {
    var responseData = JSON.parse(response);
```

И дальше аки с объектом.

Comment: к чему обращаться, данные которые выводит класс они динамические

Comment: т.е. как обращаться?

Comment: приходит результат из php в response,  let jsonObj = response,
                        responseData = JSON.parse(jsonObj); и так оно ошибку выводит SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON dat

Comment: не заметил что результат приходит  string(27){"968":"phones","970":"iphone"}, string(27) как то убирается?

Comment: @аноним походу где-то через print_r или var_dump еще выводятся данные

Comment: добавьте в вопрос весь ajax запрос, посмотреть.

Comment: так и есть, был var_dump, поправил на echo и заработало=)